# Iterate through Outlook subfolders and inbox

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have this code below which loops through the inbox, searching for a specific e-mail address entered on the worksheet's column E. it will return the last e-mail sent date to column b.

```
Sub ()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim eFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim icounter As Long
Dim lrow As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("-")

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("vlookup").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
For i = olFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

 If TypeOf olFolder.Items(i) Is MailItem Then
        Set olMail = olFolder.Items(i)
            For icounter = 2 To lastrow
            If InStr(olMail.SenderEmailAddress, ws.Cells(icounter, 5).Value) > 0 Then 'qualify the cell
                With ws
                   lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                       .Range("B" & lrow + 1).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
                       .Range("A" & lrow + 1).Value = olMail.SenderEmailAddress
                End With
            End If
            Next icounter
        End If
    Next i
    Set olFolder = Nothing



    End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to loop through the subfolders. I've checked SO and found this code below from [Can I iterate through all Outlook emails in a folder including sub-folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272361/can-i-iterate-through-all-outlook-emails-in-a-folder-including-sub-folders?lq=1)

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

But i've never used private subs so I don't know how to combine them..

Also found this which is the combined version using the private sub i found above, but I had no luck in translating it to my code. [Outlook VBA Importing Emails from Subfolders into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527816/outlook-vba-importing-emails-from-subfolders-into-excel/33553951#33553951)

Answer (score 0):

The private sub sits in a module and is only available to that module, you can call the sub by writing:

```
Call processFolder(The Outlook.MAPIFolder)
```

This sub requires an input variable `oParent` which is in the form of Outlook.MAPIFolder.