# Retrieve Outlook email count from sent folder of the last month (through word VBA)

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I've been trying to filter my outlook sent folder in Word to get the count of the total emails from last month.

```
' Connect to outlook
Dim outlook As Object
Dim NumEmails As Long
Dim name_space As Object
Dim SentFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim criterion As String

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set name_space = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next
Set SentFolder = name_space.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "No such folder."
    Exit Sub
End If

If Month(Date) = 1 And Day(Date) < 27 Then
    ' It's January but we're reporting Decemember
    criterion = ""
ElseIf Day(Date) > 27 Then
    ' It's the end of the month; pull this month's data
    criterion = ""
Else
    ' It's not the end of the month; pull last month's data
    criterion = ""
End If
```

Is what I got so far, but I'm stuck what to put as my criterion variable and how to utilize it for filtering the folder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should find information about finding the first day and last day of a month. You can feed those dates into a Restrict similar to the way it is used in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450541/search-outlook-emails-from-vba

Answer (score 0):

With date code from one of multiple possible sites you can filter like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ItemsByMonth()

    Dim myStart As Date
    Dim myEnd As Date

    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim name_space As Object
    Dim SentFolder As Object

    Dim oItems As Items
    Dim oitem As Object

    Dim strRestriction As String
    Dim oResItems As Items

    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set name_space = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' http://www.anysitesupport.com/vba-time-and-date-functions/
    If Day(Date) < 27 Then
        'Last day of previous month
        myEnd = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)
    Else
        'Last day of month
        myEnd = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
    End If

    ' First day of the myEnd month
    myStart = DateSerial(Year(myEnd), Month(myEnd), 1)

    Set SentFolder = name_space.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set oItems = SentFolder.Items

    strRestriction = "[SentOn] <= '" & myEnd & "' AND [SentOn] >= '" & myStart & "'"
    Set oResItems = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)
    Debug.Print oResItems.count

ExitRoutine:
    Set outlook = Nothing
    Set name_space = Nothing
    Set SentFolder = Nothing
    Set oItems = Nothing
    Set oResItems = Nothing

End Sub
```