# Emails to a distribution group aren't MailItems?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm trying to write a VBA script for Outlook 2007 that moves a user's mail to an "Expired" folder if it's older than 89 days. I have code to do this, but it doesn't seem to work for aged emails that were to a distribution group that includes the end user. It works for emails just sent to the end user.

I combined code I found online for a) moving emails when they are a certain number of days old (http://www.slipstick.com/developer/macro-move-aged-mail/), and b) recursing through a folder to apply the code to subfolders as well ([Can I iterate through all Outlook emails in a folder including sub-folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272361/can-i-iterate-through-all-outlook-emails-in-a-folder-including-sub-folders)). This code recurses through the Inbox folder and subfolders to move all aged mail.

It more or less works, but for some reason emails to a distribution list that includes the end user are not being picked up. The only remarkable check I have is that

```
    If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem"
```

Are distribution list emails not considered MailItems? If not, how do I make sure to catch those too?

Here is the complete code:

```
    Public Sub MoveAgedMail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

        Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
        Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim objVariant As Variant
        Dim lngMovedItems As Long
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim intDateDiff As Integer
        Dim strDestFolder As String
        Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        Set objOutlook = Application
        Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

        ' Call processFolder
        processFolder objSourceFolder


    End Sub

    Public Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

            Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
            Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
            Dim oItem As Object
            Dim intCount As Integer
            Dim intDateDiff As Long
            Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

        ' "Expired" folder at same level as Inbox for sending aged mail        
        Set objDestFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Expired")

            For Each oItem In oParent.Items
                If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
                    Set oMail = oItem

                    ' Check if email is older than 89 days
                    intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", oMail.SentOn, Now)


                    If intDateDiff > 89 Then

                   ' Move to "Expired" folder
                    oMail.Move objDestFolder

                    End If
                End If

            Next oItem

        ' Recurse through subfolders
            If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
                For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                    processFolder oFolder
                Next
            End If
            Set objDestFolder = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do the problem mails not pass the `TypeName()` test?

Comment: I think its batter to use For Loop With Step Backwards then using `For Each` when moving `mailitems`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, do not use `for each` if you are modifying a collection - that will cause your code to skip half the items.

Secondly, do not just loop through *all* items in a folder, this is extremely inefficient. Use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext`.

Try something like the following (VB script):

```
d = Now - 89
strFilter = "[SentOn]  < '" & Month(d) & "/" & Day(d) & "/" & Year(d) & "'"
set oItems = oParent.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
for i = oItems.Count to 1 step -1
  set oItem = oItems.Item(i)
  Debug.Print oItem.Subject & " " & oItem.SentOn
next
```

Comment: This was helpful. I changed my script to the following.

Comment: I'll post it as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to process **`Expired`** Folder

```
    ' Recurse through subfolders
        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
            Debug.Print oFolder
                ' No need to process Expired folder
                If oFolder.Name <> "Expired" Then
                    processFolder oFolder
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

also try using down loop when moving mail items, see [Dmitry Streblechenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko) example

---

***Edit***

[Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx)

*Complete Code- Tested on Outlook 2010*

```
Sub MoveAgedMail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'   // Call ProcessFolder
    ProcessFolder olInbox

End Sub

Function ProcessFolder(ByVal Parent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim iDateDiff As Long
    Dim vMail As Variant
    Dim olItems As Object
    Dim sFilter As String

    iDateDiff = Now - 89
    sFilter = "[SentOn]  < '" & Month(iDateDiff) & "/" & Day(iDateDiff) & "/" & Year(iDateDiff) & "'"

'   // Loop through the items in the folder backwards
    Set olItems = Parent.Items.Restrict(sFilter)

    For iCount = olItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set vMail = olItems.Item(iCount)

        Debug.Print vMail.Subject ' helps me to see where code is currently at 

'       // Filter objects for emails
        If vMail.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print vMail.SentOn

'           //  Retrieve a folder for the destination folder
            Set DestFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Expired")

'           // Move the emails to the destination folder
            vMail.Move DestFolder

'           // Count number items moved
            iCount = iCount + 1

        End If
    Next

'   // Recurse through subfolders
    If (Parent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
        For Each Folder In Parent.Folders
            If Folder.Name <> "Expired" Then ' skip Expired folder
                Debug.Print Folder.Name
                ProcessFolder Folder
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Debug.Print "Moved " & iCount & " Items"

End Function
```

Comment: Looping through all items is still a very bad idea. Try to run the script on a folder that contains 10,000+ items. You should also never use multiple dot notation in a loop (Parent.Items.Item(iCount)) - cache the Items collection before entering the loop.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko How about now? tested on folder that contains  `23,146 items`

Comment: Why are you setting DestFolder to Nothing inside the loop while you still need to process more items? DoEvents  is also not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code now. Originally, I moved my old mail to an "Expired" folder and had autoarchive delete the messages, but I was having issues with autoarchive on some machines. I rewrote the script to delete old email. It uses Dmitry Streblechenko's suggestions, and it seems to work.

```
Public Sub DeleteAgedMail()
   Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
   Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
   Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
   Dim objSourceFolderSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder

   Set objOutlook = Application
   Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
   Set objSourceFolderSent = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

   processFolder objSourceFolder
   processFolder objSourceFolderSent
   emptyDeleted  
End Sub

Public Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
   Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
   Dim oItem As Object
   Dim intDateDiff As Long
   Dim d As Long
   Dim strFilter As String    

   d = Now - 89
   strFilter = "[SentOn]  < '" & Month(d) & "/" & Day(d) & "/" & Year(d) & "'"
   Set oItems = oParent.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
   For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
       Set oItem = oItems.Item(i)
       If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
         oItem.UserProperties.Add "Deleted", olText
         oItem.Save
         oItem.Delete
       End If
   Next
   If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
       For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
           processFolder oFolder
       Next
   End If   
End Sub

Public Sub emptyDeleted()
   Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
   Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
   Dim objDeletedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
   Dim objProperty As Outlook.UserProperty

   Set objOutlook = Application
   Set myNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set objDeletedFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

   For Each objItem In objDeletedFolder.Items
       Set objProperty = objItem.UserProperties.Find("Deleted")
       If TypeName(objProperty) <> "Nothing" Then
           objItem.Delete
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

If you want to just move emails and not delete them, like in my original code, you could get rid of the emptyDeleted() function, change

```
oItem.UserProperties.Add "Deleted", olText
oItem.Save
oItem.Delete
```

back to

```
 oItem.Move objDestFolder
```

and add these two lines back to the processFolder() function:

```
Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder      
Set objDestFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Expired")
```