# Outlook VBA - How to run a script for Inbox and subfolders

Tags: vba, outlook

How would I get a macro to run on the Inbox **and** any subfolders?

This only applies to the root folder

```
Set xInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Comment: `For Each Folder in xInboxFld`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel vba: Looping through all subfolders in Outlook email to find an email with certain subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346183/excel-vba-looping-through-all-subfolders-in-outlook-email-to-find-an-email-with)

Comment: This is how I have solved the problem:


`Set xInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set xCurrentFld = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    
If xCurrentFld.Parent = xInboxFld Then
Set xInboxFld = xCurrentFld
End If`

Answer (score -1):

```
dim subFolder 
for each subFolder in xInboxFld.Folders
  MsgBox subFolder.Name
next
```