# Scraping Outlook E-mails using VBA - type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm currently working on a macro to scrape Outlook e-mails and attachments. Having a minor type mismatch error, hoping that someone can point out what data type I need.

So I'm aware there's a large practicality hurdle that I'll need to face at some point. Right now I'm focusing on making things work, then optimizing.

```vb
Sub FetchEmailData()
    Dim appOutlook As Object
    Dim olNs As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim iRow As Integer
    
    ' Get/create Outlook Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If appOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set olNs = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 == Inbox for some reason
    
    For iRow = 1 To olFolder.Items.Count
        'Check if we care about the e-mail
        Call SaveEmailAttachment(olFolder.Items.Item(iRow))
        'Go onto the next one if we don't
        
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).To
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Size        
    Next iRow
End Sub
    
Sub SaveEmailAttachment(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
     
    saveFolder = ThisWorkbook.Names("EmailAttachmentSavePath").RefersToRange.Value2
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

So the data type mismatch is because I'm sending an Outlook folder item, but the receiving macro is expecting an Outlook `MailItem`. I know I need to get both of them to the same item type, probably via a `dim`, but I'm not quite sure which one is better to use, and how I'd need to adapt the `SaveEmailAttachment` code to properly compensate.

Bonus question: Is there a way to scrape a subfolder by name?

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: I apologize - Call SaveEmailAttachment(olFolder.Items.Item(iRow)) - it's when I try to pass the e-mail to the save-down macro.

Comment: I'm not getting any error- also are trying to loop through only items with attachment or all items?

Comment: see if this helps on subfolders https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683587/4539709

Comment: Not all e-mails have attachments, but I thought that was handled with the "for each objatt" line

Answer (score 1):

test for the TypeOf item and if it is a mailItem pass it.

```
If TypeOf olFolder.Items.Item(iRow) Is MailItem Then
    Call SaveEmailAttachment(olFolder.Items.Item(iRow))
end if
```